# capture mutex from lambda within member function

Tags: c++, multithreading, lambda

this piece of code bellow is just an example, it runs just fine because there is nothing bad that could happen since it's just an example and not a real world program.

Although the code runs I'm afraid that there must be something bad because I'm getting segmentation faults in my other project which uses a pattern which is the same as this example..
(I wrote this example to make question understandable, and after this example is a function
from my project which is accesses by multiple threads)

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>

std::mutex mtx;

struct foo
{
    int var = 0;

    void bar()
    {
        std::thread t([&, this](){

            for(int i = 1; i < 8; ++i)
            {
                mtx.lock();
                var++;
                mtx.unlock();
                std::cout << "inside bar" << std::endl;
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
            }});
        t.detach();
    }
};

int main()
{
    foo x, y, z;
    x.bar();
    y.bar();
    z.bar();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(100));
    return 0;
}
```

as I said the above program works but I'm not sure if it is safe because something similar does not work in my current project...

here is a function from my project (similar to the above bar member function) which is accessed by different objects of the same class in the same time,
changing a color and drawing a widget which causes segmentation faults:

```
std::mutex mtx;

void HField::blink()
{
    std::thread t([&, this](){
        Gdk::RGBA color = Gdk::RGBA("Medium Blue");
        Gdk::RGBA temp = m_background;  // m_background is a RGBA member

        for(int i = 1; i < 8; ++i)
        {
            mtx.lock();
            if(i % 2) m_background = color;
            else m_background = temp;
            mtx.unlock();
            queue_draw();
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
        }
        m_background = temp;
        queue_draw();});

    t.detach();
}
```

Comment: For what it's worth, in the second example you are assigning to `m_background` outside the mutex.

Comment: And you will definitely have problems if the thread manages to outlive the `this` it captures.

Comment: @dlf you're wright, I put lock/unlock before/after every variable but still getting program chrash hm..

Comment: I removed lambda and created an extra function which is called by threads and it looks that works but I'm not sure, there must be something wrong with my usage of lambda but I don't know what

Comment: And how about gdb?